# Passing a parameter to a partial view in mvc to load a specific db row

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, partial-views

I'm developing an mvc 4 application and I'm just about done. The only problem I'm having is at the end of a multi-page form that the user fills out, I want to have a summary page that displays all of the information they entered in. I figured the easiest way to do this would be by using partial views to display the form data from the different pages they entered the data in on. From page to page on the form, an int parameter is passed which represents the id number in the database for the form they are filling out (the user is emailed that id in advance because they need it to login). The problem is, once the form is completed and that summary page is loaded, the main view loads with the id parameter (so for example its mysite.com/vendor/quotesummary/22), but I can't figure out how to pass that parameter, to the partial views in order to load the correct data. So here's what my code looks like:

In my controller:

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult QuoteSummary(int id = 0)
    {
        General_Info general_info = unitOfWork.General_Info_Repository.GetByID(id);
        return View(new QuotesViewModel(general_info));
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [ChildActionOnly]
    public ActionResult GenInfoSummary()
    {

        return View(new QuotesViewModel());
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [ChildActionOnly]
    public ActionResult QuoteDataSummary()
    {

        return View(new QuotesViewModel());
    }
```

And then in my QuoteSummary view I have:

```
@model SourceMvc.DAL.QuotesViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "QuoteSummary";
 }

<h2>Quote Summary</h2>

@Html.Partial("QuoteSummaryChildOne", new SourceMvc.DAL.QuotesViewModel());
@Html.Partial("QuoteSummaryChildTwo", new SourceMvc.DAL.QuotesViewModel());
```

And like I said, my QuoteSummary is loading with the correct id parameter, even though that means nothing until I can get that parameter passed down to the partial views.

I've been trying to figure this out for two days now and I feel like the answer has got to be simple which is why its been so frustrating. Any help you guys can provide would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: 1) you are passing a row to your partial, but it seems you should be passing an id. 2) you are NOT using your child action. For that, you should make a call resembling @Html.Action()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you put an action in the view where the partial view is to be rendered

```
@Html.Action("GenInfoSummary","Home")
```

And have the action result render a partial view like this

```
[HttpGet]
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult GenInfoSummary(int id = 0)
{

    return PartailView(new QuotesViewModel());
}
```

Comment: Hey ojhawkins, 

Sorry about taking so long to get back to you, but this is the solution tha worked for me, so thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult QuoteSummary(int id = 0)
{
    General_Info general_info = unitOfWork.General_Info_Repository.GetByID(id);
    return View(new QuotesViewModel(general_info));
}

[HttpGet]
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult GenInfoSummary(int id = 0)
{

    return View(new QuotesViewModel(/* whatever info you need from id */));
}

[HttpGet]
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult QuoteDataSummary(int id = 0)
{

    return View(new QuotesViewModel(/* whatever info you need from id */));
}
```

And in your view, assuming your QuotesViewModel has an Id property

```
@model SourceMvc.DAL.QuotesViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "QuoteSummary";
 }

<h2>Quote Summary</h2>

@Html.Action("GenInfoSummary", Model.Id);
@Html.Action("QuoteDataSummary", Model.Id);
```

Comment: LOL! I was workin thru best answer in my head just as you post, but the best i can do is indicate. the rest is up to OP ;)

Comment: @DaveA indeed. looks like I need some rest

Answer (score 0):

That values name is coming from the routing definition.  That's why you can't set it, the routing pulled it from the URL and that value is taking precedence. The solution to your problem is either to reset it in the action, as was suggested or adjust your routing definitions.